# Running threads inside process

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, function, multiprocessing

Is it possible to run threads inside a function(the function will run as a process), and if how many?

Here is the example:

```
def process_one():
    def one():
        while True:
            print("one")
            time.sleep(1)

    def two():
        while True:
            print("two")
            time.sleep(1)

    def three():
        while True:
            print("three")
            time.sleep(1)

    a = Thread(target=one)
    b = Thread(target=two)
    c = Thread(target=three)
    a.start()
    b.start()
    c.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=process_one)
    p1.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can even test this very example with starting it and using task manager/activity monitor/system monitor. You should see one parent and one child process. Child process should have 3 threads started.

As for the question on how many threads can be started, it really depends on what is your use case.

Couple of tips on given example:

1. You have to use `join` on at least threads in this example. If you don't, child process finishes quickly,
2. Since threads are started in child process, you have to pay attention to how you handle threads life cycle,
3. Since you can kill parent, child process continues to live, so that is another thing to pay attention to.

There may be other corner cases, but you will certainly have to research thoroughly on this if you decide go with concurrency using processes and threads.